# How to use out side the loop in foreach values

Tags: php

I have one array, from which I need to return a string like this: **propertyType=Apartment&propertyType=Villament**. I'm trying like this but when outside the loop I am not able to get the all values, getting only first values how can I do this?, **these values I want to use out side the loop.**

```
<?php
$response = [
    "0" => "Apartment",
    "1"=> "Villament" 
];

foreach ($response as $key => $item) {
  $ppp = "propertyType=".$item.'&';//propertyType=Apartment&propertyType=Villament&
}
echo $ppp;
?>
```

Comment: you can access it by subscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$respose =  
Array (
    "0" => "Apartment",
    "1"=> "Villament" 
);
$count = count ($respose); 


 foreach ($respose as $key => $item) {
  $ppp .= "propertyType=".$item.'&';//propertyType=Apartment&propertyType=Villament&
}
 $ppp = rtrim($ppp,'&');
echo $ppp ;
?>
```

Just copy past the code. I hope this will work.
Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah, welcome. My question is what made you post this kinda question then ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$respose =  
Array (
    "0" => "Apartment",
    "1"=> "Villament" 
);
$count = count ($respose); 

$ppp = [];
// $str_ppp = '';
foreach ($respose as $key => $item) {
  $ppp[] = "propertyType=".$item;
 // or in your way
 // $str_ppp .= "propertyType=".$item.'&';
}
echo implode('&',$ppp) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$respose =  
Array (
    "0" => "Apartment",
    "1"=> "Villament" 
);
$count = count ($respose); 

$ppp ="";
 foreach ($respose as $key => $item) {
    $ppp.="propertyType=".$item.'&';//propertyType=Apartment&propertyType=Villament&
}
echo $ppp ;
?>
```

You need to concatenate $ppp values. For this use `.=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$response = array_map(function($v) {
  return 'propertyType='.$v; 
}, $response);
```

So, the newly formatted array becomes:

```
Array
(
  [0] => propertyType=Apartment
  [1] => propertyType=Villament
)
```

Now, you simply need to convert this to string with `&` as the glue

```
echo implode('&', $response); // propertyType=Apartment&propertyType=Villament
```

Comment: Way nice than using `.=`

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple.

```
<?php
$respose =  
Array (
   "0" => "Apartment",
   "1"=> "Villament" 
);
$ppp ='propertyType='.$respose[0].'&propertyType='.$respose[1];
echo $ppp;
```